# Uncaught TypeError when using `unstable_getServerSession`

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware, next-auth

I'm currently trying to use `unstable_getServerSession` in my middleware.ts file. This is because I'd like to do some upstream service calls prior to rendering the UI, and these calls require data found in the `session`.

The issue I'm having is that I keep getting the following error when I use `unstable_getServerSession`:

[image]

I have looked everywhere to see what might be causing this, but I can't find any answers as to why this is happening. Wondering if anyone can shed some light on this.

Code for reference:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from "./pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]";

// using NextRequest & NextResponse
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
    const session = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
    return;
}

// using NextApiRequest & NextApiResponse
export async function middleware(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const session = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **unstable_getServerSession** :
> This method was renamed to getServerSession. See the [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#unstable_getserversession)

```js
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
//...
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
  return;
}
```